# What is the proper way to use a custom View with the GridView?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-gridview

Bear with me, I am very new to Android dev. I'm trying to make a simple app with 9 cards arranged in a 3x3 grid. To do this, I decided to use the GridView layout along with a custom View for each card. I based it mostly on the [GridView guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Here is what I have:

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/grid_cards"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:numColumns="3"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
   />
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView grid_cards = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_cards);
        grid_cards.setAdapter(new CardAdapter(this));

        grid_cards.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "position = " + position,
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### CardAdapter.java

```
public class CardAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mSize;

    public CardAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        mSize = 9;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mSize;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null; // XXX
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0; // XXX
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CardView cardView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            cardView = new CardView(mContext);
            cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            cardView = (CardView) convertView;
        }

        // force redraw. XXX: truly required?
        cardView.invalidate();

        return cardView;
    }
}
```

### CardView.java

```
public class CardView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public CardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0,
                        canvas.getWidth()-1,
                        canvas.getHeight()-1, paint);
    }
}
```

What I get instead is nothing. The app does not crash, but none of the cards are drawn. Adding some `Log.i()` calls seems to indicate that the `onDraw()` of `CardView` is not even called. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you never called super.onDraw(canvas)

```
   @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.onDraw(canvas); //<== this line is needed to begin drawing on the canvas
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0,
                        canvas.getWidth()-1,
                        canvas.getHeight()-1, paint);
    }
```

you need to explicitly set the derived View dimensions using setMinimumWidth() and setMinimumHeight()

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference. Like I mentioned in the post, even if I put some Log.i() calls in the onDraw(), it doesn't even seem to be called at all. Does it work for you?

Comment: can you set the cardView width and height ?

Comment: That was it, thank you! (For reference for others, you need to explicitly set the derived View dimensions using setMinimumWidth() and setMinimumHeight()).